# Что такое multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, http, файлы, formdata

Появилась потребность залить файлы через на vk-сервер через его API. В справке по работе с API сказано:

> файлы должны передаваться в формате multipart/form-data на url сервер

Однако, не понятно что такое multiform и не понятно как передавать эти файлы. Документацию в гугле не нашел. Прошу тыкнуть ссылкой. Единственное что, прочитал статью на вики про multiform. Там указан пример формирования формы, однако как её отправлять и сформировать я не нашёл.

Comment: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...`

Comment: Не понял. Передать запрос надо через Java

Comment: [How can I make a multipart/form-data POST request using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java) [Upload files by sending multipart request programmatically](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically)

Comment: Ок. Для будущих поколений (если вдруг умрут ссылки) ищите в гугле вот так: `java multipart/form-data`

Comment: Я это находил. Там используются сторонние библиотеки и не объсняется сам файл

Comment: А по второй ссылке ходили? Там же расписано всё от А до Я и даже приложены готовый класс `MultipartUtility.java` и тестовая утилита `MultipartFileUploader.java`. Бери готовое и используй.

Comment: Если что, вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests есть пример на пальцах по использованию `java.net.URLConnection` где, в том числе, приводится и пример отправки данных с использованием  `multipart/form-data` метода.