# Как перевести документ в формат multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, android, файлы, api, вконтакте

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при работе с VK API, чтобы получить ссылку для загрузки фото в сам ВК, есть метод `VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest()`, который возвращает мне ссылку для загрузки.

НО. Такого метода нет для документов, видеозаписей и аудиозаписей. В документации нашёл это (см. скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так я получаю документы из памяти устройства:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.AddPicture)), SELECT_IMAGE);

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
                Uri docsUri = data.getData();
                // Дальше работаю с фотками норм
            }
        }
    }
```

Это пример для фото. С документами действую аналогично.
Как после того, как я получил документ перевести его в multipart/form-data?
Спасибо:)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое multipart/form-data?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483116/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю не нужно ничего переводить. Посмотрите [тут!](https://javatalks.ru/topics/47926). Здесь есть пример как загрузить файл и там **multipart/form-data** идет просто как **свойство(property)** запроса.

Вот основная часть запроса:

```
URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
            true);
```

Comment: Возможно это действительно поможет. А где мне тут нужно передать собственно файл?

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант по проще. Просто используйте одну из библиотек:
https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md

Тогда например код для загрузки фото будет выглядеть так:

```
PhotoUpload serverResponse = 
vk.photos().getWallUploadServer(actor).execute();
WallUploadResponse uploadResponse = vk.upload().photoWall(serverResponse.getUploadUrl(), file).execute();
List<Photo> photoList = vk.photos().saveWallPhoto(actor, uploadResponse.getPhoto())
 .server(uploadResponse.getServer())
 .hash(uploadResponse.getHash())
 .execute();

Photo photo = photoList.get(0); 
String attachId = "photo" + 
photo.getOwnerId() + "_" + photo.getId();
GetResponse getResponse = vk.wall().post(actor)
.attachments(attachId)
.execute();
```

Comment: Идея хорошая. Однако там как и в официальном sdk нет такого метода для документов.